# Displaying Console and Debugger at same time in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

The default layout has the debugger and console on separate tabs. I see that I can pop the Console as a floating window and even add it as a tab to the "Variables" or "Watches" pane in the Debugger tab. I'd like to have a layout that displays the Console and Debugger information at the same time (like a split pane, or a separate pane on the "Debugger" tab because it is useful to see the output to console while stepping through the debugger.

Any suggestions on how this can be accomplished? I'm using IntelliJ 13.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you can do is to drag one of the window icons(either debugger or console) to the other window and put onto the portion as you want. There will be purple highlighted box. This is how my debugger/console windows look like:

[image: Debugger and Console on the same window]

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to have the debugger "Watch" show up as a 4th column but this works well enough.

Comment: @SanjivJivan yes, watch window can't be paralleled with others. It seems only 3 window sections are supported now in IntelliJ 14.

Comment: Was able to do this in CLion after some fiddling. CLion's debugger has a fantastic option "Show watches in variables tab", which has to be turner OFF first, in order for the third tab to appear. Then one can rearrange tabs and turn the option back on.

Comment: In Linux Mint Cinnamon, I had to Alt-Ctrl click and drag to move the console tab